# WSO2 - ESB server 4.7 Hangs- when an invalid json format is given as input for rest API

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

A REST API has been defined ESB. What we have observed is if the json format (invalid json),
the request is hanging and the server doesn't give any response. Ideally it should throw some
error at least and it should not hang.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation in WSO2 4.8.1. Try to change **JsonStreamBuilder** in your **axis2.xml** to **JsonBuilder** from (**org.apache.synapse.commons.json**) or use your own implementation.