# WSO2 ESB - continue if request failed

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

My question follows [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22817554/wso2-esb-server-4-7-hangs-when-an-invalid-json-format-is-given-as-input-for-r) question.

Server hangs in random times and every time it happens if I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> once on server it throws several exceptions and after that everything get back to normal.

It seems sometimes (not all of times) if someone send a request with invalid inputs or `end-point` response with invalid output server hangs and by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> server discards that request and starts to process other blocked requests.

So I think I need to set something like if request didn't respond by for example 1 minutes don't hang and just discard this request.

I've found [HTTP Transport Properties](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/HTTP+Transport+Properties#HTTPTransportProperties-NO_KEEPALIVE) in ESB documentations. But [NO_KEEPALIVE](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/HTTP+Transport+Properties#HTTPTransportProperties-NO_KEEPALIVE) value is not well-documented and I'm not sure about its behavior.

What I'm asking is if `NO_KEEPALIVE` value is proper in this case or not.

If another approach is best practice in this situation it is appreciated too.

### Code:

```
<resource methods="POST" uri-template="/register">
    <inSequence>
        <property description="Store Token" expression="$trp:Authorization" name="token" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <property description="Store JSON" expression="json-eval($.)" name="json" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <property description="Store MessageId" expression="get-property('MessageID')" name="MESSAGE_ID" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <dbreport description="log request">
            <connection>
                <pool>
                    <dsName>jdbc/dc</dsName>
                </pool>
            </connection>
            <statement>
                <sql><![CDATA[INSERT INTO Request (Service, Action, JSON, Requestor, MessageId) values (?,?,?,?,?);]]></sql>
                <parameter type="VARCHAR" value="ServiceV3"/>
                <parameter type="VARCHAR" value="Register"/>
                <parameter expression="get-property('json')" type="VARCHAR"/>
                <parameter expression="get-property('token')" type="VARCHAR"/>
                <parameter expression="get-property('MESSAGE_ID')" type="VARCHAR"/>
            </statement>
        </dbreport>
        <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>{"value":"$1"}</format>
            <args>
                <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.port"/>
            </args>
        </payloadFactory>
        <property description="Force HTTP 1" name="FORCE_HTTP_1.0" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
        <property description="Authorization" expression="get-property('token')" name="Authorization" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
        <send>
            <endpoint key="Register"/>
        </send>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
        <property description="Store JSON" expression="json-eval($.)" name="json" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <dbreport description="log response">
            <connection>
                <pool>
                    <dsName>jdbc/dc</dsName>
                </pool>
            </connection>
            <statement>
                <sql><![CDATA[INSERT INTO Response (Service, Action, Requestor, JSON, MessageId) values (?,?,?,?,?);]]></sql>
                <parameter type="VARCHAR" value="ServiceV3"/>
                <parameter type="VARCHAR" value="Register"/>
                <parameter expression="get-property('token')" type="VARCHAR"/>
                <parameter expression="get-property('json')" type="VARCHAR"/>
                <parameter expression="get-property('MESSAGE_ID')" type="VARCHAR"/>
            </statement>
        </dbreport>
        <send/>
    </outSequence>
    <faultSequence>
        <payloadFactory description="Error" media-type="json">
            <format>{"Message":"Error"}</format>
            <args/>
        </payloadFactory>
        <send/>
    </faultSequence>
</resource>
```

### Error Logs:

This error has occurred several times frequently and finally at `17:53` server has froze without any further logs:

> TID: [-1234] [] [2019-06-24 17:53:24,643] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender} -  Unexpected error during sending message out {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender}
>   org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Unexpected symbol: COMMA
>       at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)

In the next day at `11:14` when I've pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> everything got back to normal. And a huge amount of blocked requests has started to proceed. The first error log at that time was this and this `warn` message usually occurs. I'm not sure if it has anything to do with freezing server.

> [2019-06-25 11:14:41,147]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} -  Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-1522 Socket Timeout : 180000 Remote Address : /***.***.**.**:***** {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler}

Comment: Can you share the code along with logs?

Comment: @amg_amit sure. I've updated my question

Comment: you can try to use a mediator validator, check out this page: https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Validate+Mediator#cbf91efae12e49e78452017c02dec875

Comment: @JorgeInfanteOsorio Thanks, I'll try it.